Change the index access method in PostgreSQL?
I have a bunch of PostgreSQL (v14 or 15) indexes over a few dozen tables that use B-Trees for their access method. We want to change them to hashes as we don't do inequality operations on them, and hash is about 30% faster on average for equality operations from the data I've seen.
I see in the PostgreSQL docs that indexes can be altered and reindexed, but there doesn't seem to be a method for changing the access method. Is that possible and I'm just missing on how to perform it? Or do I need to drop and recreate the indexes with the appropriate indexing method?
Thanks.

No, not possible, you have to create a new index and drop the old one. Performance depends on your queries, not just the type of index. A claim about 30% performance improvements is a little premature.

That's unfortunate, but kinda figured.
Most of our queries are recursive table joins for graph operations or basic selects on unordered data, so I can't imagine the performance would be anything but better.

Your imagination and reality, are two different things. Check the query plans first, to avoid surprises. For example you disable the option for index-only scans, no more multi column indexes, no min-max aggregates and no ordering. I haven't used a single hash index the last 20 years, there was never a use case. Again, check your query plans before moving on.

Did a test on a small table with 6.2 million records and replaced the btree index by a hash index: The btree index was 125MB in size, the hash index is 167MB in size. And no significant change in performance, both were equally fast on a fast machine.

I didn't realize that hash indexes couldn't be used for multi-column indexes - that wasn't mentioned in the access method documentation (but was the multi-column index documentation ). We primarily use multi-column indexes, so that throws a spanner in that idea.
Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Drop the Btree index using:
DROP INDEX indexname;

Create the hash index using :
CREATE INDEX column_name_hash_idx ON tablename USING HASH (columnname); 

The acccess method will pick up the hash index retrival only when '=' is used because hash indexes are optimised for equality comparisons .
